# Return count of how many occurrences there are

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that looks like this:

| user_id | other_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 123 | date1 |
| 213454678 | 123 | date2 |

Here, user_id is a multikey and is re-occurring for some entries. Date is irrelevant for this task.
I tried this query:

`select user_id, count(user_id) as count from exp_pixel_data group by user_id;`

And this returned

| user_id | count |
| --- | --- |
| 123324345456456576587 | 7 |
| 453545435343455343453 | 3 |
| 777676766776675654454 | 2 |
| 345565664545665654645 | 1 |

This result tells me how often a user_id is occurring in the table. This may be a good start, but now i need how often this counts are occurring in the result of the last query. So the question is, how many user_ids occur 7 times in the table?
I need a SQL query which returns something like this:

| count | times_ocurring |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 3 | 2 |

and so on.

This means that 123 times there are user_ids that occur one time in the main table, 100 times user_ids that occur 2 Times and 2 times user_ids that occur 3 times.

Comment: Could you please add you query? This way, we have a starting point to give you suggestions from

Comment: Yes of course. 
My query was

```mysql> select user_id  , count(user_id) from exp_pixel_data group by user_id;```

and it returned only 
user_id | count(user_id)
so the occurences of all user_ids.

Comment: The query produces the expected result, but it doesn't match the data you provided.  If this isn't what you wanted, you'll need to describe your actual requirement.  Can you add some minimal data to the question, along with the exact result expected, given that specific data?

Comment: I'll wait for the description.  Sorry.  Not enough detail to even guess.

Comment: Please share more details, and please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: I have edited the question, it should be more clarified now.

Comment: @Aleks It looks like my original guess was accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible you're trying to do this (count the counts)?

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7c8bddb5cd64c47de16ffe119ebd5e86)

```
SELECT COUNT(xcount) AS count_of_counts
     , xcount
  FROM (SELECT user_id
             , COUNT(user_id) AS xcount
          FROM exp_pixel_data
         GROUP BY user_id
       ) xxx
 GROUP BY xcount
 ORDER BY COUNT(xcount)
;
```

and with MySQL, we can use the derived column name in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT COUNT(xcount) AS count_of_counts
     , xcount
  FROM (SELECT user_id
             , COUNT(user_id) AS xcount
          FROM exp_pixel_data
         GROUP BY user_id
       ) xxx
 GROUP BY xcount
 ORDER BY count_of_counts
;
```

**Result (given test data below):**

```
+-----------------+--------+
| count_of_counts | xcount |
+-----------------+--------+
|               1 |      5 |
|               2 |      2 |
|               2 |      1 |
+-----------------+--------+
```

**Setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE exp_pixel_data (user_id   int, val  int default 0);

INSERT INTO exp_pixel_data (user_id) VALUES
    (12345)
  , (12345)
  , (12399)
  , (12399)
  , (12388)
  , (12377)
  , (12355)
  , (12355)
  , (12355)
  , (12355)
  , (12355)
;
```